# Exception in WPF xaml in Windows XP .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, windows-xp, .net-framework-version

I have built a WPF application with .NET 4.6.1.

after that i downgraded to 4.0 because it needs to run in Windows XP

The problem is that i run into a problem during the start of the programm in Windows XP.

[image]

here my xaml:

```
 <Window x:Class="ETest_Scanner.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Title="E-Test Barcode Formatter" Height="200" Width="450" 
 Topmost="True" StateChanged="Window_StateChanged" Icon="IMG/scanner.ico" 
  Background="#FF919191">
   <Grid>
      <Label Content="{Binding BarcodeScanner.ScannedBarcode, 
  FallbackValue=AnyError}" Margin="10" FontSize="72" 
  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
  </Window>
```

how can i prevent that the error occures?

it seems that he has a problem with the namespaces?

this only happens in windows XP in windows 10 & windows 7 it works perfectly.

thanks in advance

EDIT:

i tried to create a new project which was 4.0 straight away.

the problem then was that the library, `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;` was not available in .NET 4.0

Now i could not access the `CallerMemberName` for my `NotifyPropertyChanged`.

i decided to create a class with the namespace `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`so the compiler thinks that i have the class available, looked like something like this:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public class CallerMemberName : Attribute
    {
    }
}
```

now the build was fine but i still have the same problem as shown in the image above.

Comment: Your Windows XP might be a 32-bit OS. Make sure you build your app targeting x86 platform, not Any Cpu or x64. That could be why you're getting that exception.

Comment: @Jon i already saw that on an other platform where a similar problem occured and fixed that but that didnt do the trick, and yes it is a 32bit OS. still thanks for your input!

Comment: Can you create a new WPF project targeting .NET 4.0, and see if you get the same result, instead of downgrading your project from 4.6.1?

Comment: good idea, dont know why i wasnt thinking about that. i will give you feedback when i tried. will maybe be tomorrow

Comment: @Jon i Edited my question, maybe you have another idea.

Comment: CallerMemberNameAttribute is not available in .NET 4.0. It was available from version 4.5. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices?view=netframework-4.0 VS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices?view=netframework-4.5

Comment: @NawedNabiZada yes i realized that, thats why i created my own class for it :)

Comment: Did you build for x86 32-bit build? Is the Windows XP machine 32-bit? I'm not sure that creating your own System.Runtime.CompilerServices namespace is a good idea, I would definitely not recommend doing this. Any chance you can install Visual Studio on a Windows XP virtual environment and step through the debugger?

Comment: @Jon yes it is built x86 so 32 bit. yes the windows 7 and windows xp machine are both 32 bit. no unfortunatly i have no possibility in doing that. for a workaround i migrated my application to windows forms. i still wonder though why it didnt work with wpf  i also removed INotifyPropertyChanged for test purpose and that was not the problem so CallerMemberaname is not the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

So i tried to manage this problem but i cant come up with a solution or a reasonable failure.

i decided to merge the whole application into a Windows Forms application also in .NET 4.0 and x86.

worked like a charm on the first build and also on the first test on the Windows XP and Windows 7 machine.

i will leave this question as not answered maybe somebody can come up with a solution or runs into the same problem someday

Answer (score -1):

Try adding config setting:

```
<runtime>
 <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1"/>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Would you mind telling OP what that does and why you recommend setting this?